# Plotting piecewise functions. Change colors?

Tags: matlab, graphics, graph, plot, matlab-figure

I am plotting a piecewise function, and I was wondering if it was possible to change the color of the line for each portion of the function?
For instance, have it yellow, red and green.

```
x = -10: 0.01: 10;
for k = 1 : length(x)
    if x(k) < -1
        y(k) = x(k)+2;
    elseif -1<=x(k) && x(k)<= 2
        y(k) = x(k).^2;
    else
        y(k) = -2*x(k)+8;

    end
end
plot(x, y);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want different colors you need to plot each portion separately.

The most flexible way to do that is to define the portion limits, compute an index that tells which portion each `x` belongs too (`ind` in the code below), and plot separately according to the value of that index:

```
limits = [-1 2];
ind = sum(bsxfun(@ge, x(:).', limits(:)),1); %'// how many values in limits are exceeded or
                                             % // equalled by each x. Indicates portion
hold on %// or hold all in old Matlab versions
for n = 0:numel(limits)
    plot(x(ind==n), y(ind==n)) %// plot portion
end
```

[image]

If you want to specify the line type or color of each portion, define a cell array of strings and use a different string in each call to `plot`:

```
limits = [-1 2];
linespec = {'r-','b:','g-.'}; %// should contain 1+numel(limits) elements
ind = sum(bsxfun(@ge, x(:).', limits(:)),1); %'
hold on
for n = 0:numel(limits)
    plot(x(ind==n), y(ind==n), linespec{n+1})
end
```

Comment: You and your `bsxfun` always making it :) Pretty colours help too

Comment: Yes! I didn't like [`parula`](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2014/10/13/a-new-colormap-for-matlab-part-1-introduction/) initially, but that reddish-orange is great. And the [origin of the name](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2014/12/10/a-new-colormap-for-matlab-part-4-the-name/) too!

Comment: @LuisMendo - What's interesting is that MathWorks doesn't tell you how the parula colour map was derived or computed.  They just tell you what it's supposed to mimic ([the parula bird](http://www.larkwire.com/static/content/images/ipad/LBNA1/NorthernParula.jpg)), and it's just a lookup table of 64 colours.  I'm curious to know what the thought process was to derive that colour map.  The other colour maps clearly have a mathematical equation associated to them: `hsv, jet`, etc.

Comment: @rayryeng I read somewhere that it has a perceptual base, and it was fine tuned by hand, hence the lack of a formula